# PIL Image can not open transformed image with skimage.io

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff, scikit-image

I have performed a shear and horizona flip transformations on an float array saved in a PFM file, then I have saved them as tif files through this code:

```
import os
from scipy import ndarray

  # image processing library
import skimage as sk
from skimage.transform import warp
from skimage import util
from skimage import io
import numpy as np

def shear(image_array: ndarray, shear=10):
    tf_augment = sk.transform.AffineTransform(shear=np.deg2rad(shear))
    return  warp(image_array, tf_augment, order=1, preserve_range=True, 
    mode='edge')

def horizontal_flip(image_array: ndarray):
    return image_array[:, ::-1]

image_path='./train/0006.pfm'
image_to_transform, scale=readPFM(image_path)   

flipped_image1=horizontal_flip(image_to_transform)
io.imsave("flipped_image1.tif", flipped_image1)

sheared_image1 =shear(image_to_transform,5)
io.imsave("sheared_image1.tif", sheared_image1)
```

However, when I try to open these images with PIL framework, it works with the flipped image but not with sheared one:

```
from PIL import Image
Image.open("sheared_image1.tif")
```

I got the error

```
 OSError: cannot identify image file 'sheared_image1.tif'
```

Could anyone explain to me the reason, or how to save my transformed images through skimage framework to be able to read them with PIL (I have to read them with PIL for latter purposes)

Comment: Kindly share the *"unhappy"* image.

Comment: [skimage.transform.warp](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#warp) returns a double precision floating point image, which PIL does not support in TIFF. Use skimage to [rescale and convert](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/data_types.html) the array to a data type supported by PIL.

Comment: @cgohlke Thank you for your reply, that is true, in fact the input array is of type float32, for this reason, the flip transform does not change its data type, however, the wrap has changed it to a float64 array which is not supportable by PIL.

Comment: @cgohlke unfortunately, I have read explanation afforded by you in the link, but I still not able to change the output of the wrap function to float32, I will be so gratefull if you help me how to do it :)

Comment: Try `io.imsave("sheared_image1.tif", sheared_image1.astype('float32'))`